# Console output in clay programming language

Tags: console-application, clay

I want to play around with [clay](http://tachyon.in/clay/) a little but I did not figure out how to get the output to display on the console. Is there any library function I could use? And related to this question: where can i find some documentation?

Comment: Thanks for proper tagging. I don't have enough reputation it seems to make new tags.

Comment: Just want to point out that the clay's home site is now [this one](http://claylabs.com/clay/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as though the println function should do what you want. It is implicitly imported from a standard library.

```
println("Hello, World!");
```

Documentation seems sparse, but there is a [wiki](https://github.com/jckarter/clay/wiki).

This looks like and interesting language. Thank you for pointing it out.

**Edit:**
Here is a little example I whipped up for console input.

```
main() {
    println("What is your name: ");
    var name = readLine(stdin);
    println("Hello, ", name);
}
```

It looks like the best source of information is the source code of the bundled libraries.  In this case, I looked at io/streams/streams.clay

Comment: They link to the bitbucket repo so I have missed this wiki. Thanks for sharing! About the println() function - I have used it - but I was hoping that I can display it's output somehow. In other words I have not found the equivalent of C's getch() or cin.get().

Comment: @Byakkun: I wasn't entirely sure what you meant, but I've edited my response to include an example of console input - in case it helps.